# How to set cookie on salesQuoteSaveAfterObserver in magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cookie

In my custom module **events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_quote_save_after">
        <observer name="cedapi_set_checkout_quote_id" instance="Vender\Module\Observer\SalesQuoteSaveAfter" />
    </event>
```

In my observer **SalesQuoteSaveAfter.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadata;

class SalesQuoteSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
    )
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;    
        $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        /* @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */
        $publicCookieMetadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
                                     ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
                                     ->setPath('/');
        $duration = 86400;
        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
          ->createCookieMetadata()
          ->setDuration($duration)
          ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
          ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('quoteId', $quote->getId(),$metadata);
        $this->_logger->info($this->cookieManager->getCookie('quoteId'));
    }
}
```

Not working.Any one help me

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347741/magento-2-4-cookie-not-setting-via-observer-code

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I delete a cookie.

```
public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {
    $cookieMetadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory->createCookieMetadata()->setPath('/');
    $this->_cookieManager->deleteCookie('your_cookie', $cookieMetadata);
}
```